# Конструкторы не работают

Tags: c++, структуры

Почему следующая программа не выводит `XY` в консоль?

```
struct X {
  X() { std::cout << "X"; }
};

struct Y {
  Y(const X &x) { std::cout << "Y"; }
};


int main() {
    Y y(X());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В первую очередь потому что

```
Y y(X());
```

это объявление функции. Т.е. никакого объекта тут не создается и никаких конструкторов даже и близко быть не может.

Именно из-за таких неоднозначностей имеет смысл перейти на новый синтаксис инициализации

```
Y y{X{}};
```

и будет вам ваше `XY`.

Comment: То есть это локальное объявление функции `y`? Почему вообще разрешено объявлять функции локально? Ни разу не видел, чтобы этим кто-то пользовался

Comment: @Дима: Объявления функций локально никто специально не "разрешал". Объявление функции ничем не лучше и не хуже других объявлений. Его можно делать локально просто потому, что и другие объявления можно делать локально. А специально запрещать это незачем.